# After deleting a shared folder, Ubuntu doesn't see freed disk space

Tags: directory, disk-usage, delete, free

I'm stuck, after deleting a shared folder (shift+del) I can't get back the disk space previously occupied by the folder (19GB). Full story - I've created a folder for backup and shared it on my local network between my laptop and the "old" computer. I've successfully copied everything I needed to my laptop over the local network but after deleting the folder on "old" computer I didnt get back the disk space. I didnt "unshare" the folder so I guess the problem might be somehow connected to this? Let me know what you think guys,

Thanks!

Comment: A shared folder does not take up any disk space on the computer that is connecting to it. Can you try to clarify the situation?

Comment: Yes, I have created the folder in my home folder. I shared it over my local network with permission to create and delete files, I copied files to it, I copied them to the laptop and than I deleted the folder.

Comment: You have two systems and I'm sure they are clear to you but I'm confused about which one you are talking about at different times.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that there are no processes holding files open on the shared drive. The system can hold files open in memory even if you have "removed" them. Run the following command to determine:

```
sudo lsof | grep <path-to-shared-folder>
```

i.e., if your shared folder was /var/nfs ,

```
sudo lsof | grep /var/nfs
```

After determining if any processes are holding open that shared folder, attempt to end those processes gracefully, then kill them if necessary.

Additionally, make sure that whatever network sharing server you were using has been stopped. i.e., if using samba :

```
stop smbd
status smbd
```

Comment: Hey,Thanks for the reply. I got:


lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuse.gvfsd-fuse file system /run/user/1000/gvfs
      Output information may be incomplete.

"stop smbd" gave me an error message, I dont really know what was the sharing method. I guess standard right-click ubuntu 14.04 one :)

Comment: That warning is acceptable and normal. Was that the only output you got from lsof?

Comment: Yes, that was the wole output I got.

Comment: I've tried this command with different folders and it basically means that there's no folder under this location. That would be true since I deleted the folder I previously shared, the thing is that the disk space didnt come back. Any thoughts?

Comment: Maybe this.. I did net usershare info which showed me to /var/lib/samba/usershare/ where I deleted the file named after the folder but still didnt get back the disk space. Any ideas?

Comment: Ok, what was the exact error you got when trying to stop samba? Consider killing any samba processes that remain after running the command to stop it gracefully.